# Fasthttp + fasthttprouter, trying to write middleware

Tags: go, middleware, fasthttp

I'm currently trying to write some middleware to work with fasthttp and fasthttprouter. And I'm stuck.

```
func jwt(h fasthttprouter.Handle) fasthttprouter.Handle {
myfunc := func(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx, _ fasthttprouter.Params) {
    fmt.Println(string(ctx.Request.Header.Cookie("Authorization")))
}

return myfunc
}
```

How do I run the actual handler now? I feel like i'm missing something very simple.

I've read through this blog post: [Middleware in Golang](https://medium.com/@matryer/writing-middleware-in-golang-and-how-go-makes-it-so-much-fun-4375c1246e81#.ssb07reu3/). But i'm lost.

Any ideas?

Regards

Answer (score 20, accepted):

for example, let us create a middleware function that will handle CORS using:

*[github.com/buaazp/fasthttprouter](https://github.com/buaazp/fasthttprouter)* and *[github.com/valyala/fasthttp](https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp)*

```
var (
    corsAllowHeaders     = "authorization"
    corsAllowMethods     = "HEAD,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS"
    corsAllowOrigin      = "*"
    corsAllowCredentials = "true"
)

func CORS(next fasthttp.RequestHandler) fasthttp.RequestHandler {
    return func(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {

        ctx.Response.Header.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", corsAllowCredentials)
        ctx.Response.Header.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", corsAllowHeaders)
        ctx.Response.Header.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", corsAllowMethods)
        ctx.Response.Header.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", corsAllowOrigin)

        next(ctx)
    }
}
```

Now we chain this middleware function on our Index handler and register it on the router.

```
func Index(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
    fmt.Fprint(ctx, "some-api")
}

func main() {
    router := fasthttprouter.New()
    router.GET("/", Index)

    if err := fasthttp.ListenAndServe(":8181", CORS(router.Handler)); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error in ListenAndServe: %s", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: i got these errors: undefined: fasthttprouter.Handler and undefined: fasthttprouter.Params what should i do?

Comment: @aldo import these packages `github.com/buaazp/fasthttprouter` and `github.com/valyala/fasthttp`

Comment: @KBN Even after implementing these packages I'm facing the issue aldo mentioned

Comment: @UdaySwami Maybe they updated the packages, I don't use those. So I'm not really sure.

Comment: How could i send this gfuy a cookie

Answer (score 0):

Example of auth middleware for fasthttp & fasthttprouter (new versions)

```
type Middleware func(h fasthttp.RequestHandler) fasthttp.RequestHandler
type AuthFunc func(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) bool
func NewAuthMiddleware(authFunc AuthFunc) Middleware {
    return func(h fasthttp.RequestHandler) fasthttp.RequestHandler {
        return func(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
            result, err: = authFunc(ctx)
            if result {
                h(ctx)
            } else {
                ctx.Response.SetStatusCode(fasthttp.StatusUnauthorized)
            }
        }
    }
}

func AuthCheck(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx)(bool, error) {
    return false; // for example ;)
}

// router
authMiddleware: = middleware.NewAuthMiddleware(security.AuthCheck)
    ...
router.GET("/protected", authMiddleware(handlers.ProtectedHandler))
```